# check isbn 10 number java

Tags: java, isbn

I should make a programm to control the number of an isbn 10 number. Therefore I'm not allowed to use arrays andd the input of the number has to be a char. The In method is similar to java scanner.

```
public class ISBN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("ISBN - Pruefung");
    System.out.println("=================");
    System.out.print("ISBN-Nummer: ");
    char isbn = In.read();


    int check = 0;
    int d=0;

    for (d=0; d<10; d++) {

        if ('0' <= isbn && isbn <= '9' ) {
            check = (int) ((isbn-48)*d)+check;
            if(d ==9) {
                int lastDigit = check%11;
                if(lastDigit ==10) {
                    System.out.println("x");
                }else {
                System.out.println(lastDigit);
                }
            }else {
                System.out.print(isbn);
            }

        }else {
            System.out.println(isbn + "Falsche Eingabe");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        isbn = In.read();
    }
    if (d == 10 && check%11 ==0) {
        System.out.println("wahr");
    }else {
        System.out.println("falsch");
    }



    }

}
```

I googled some isbn 10 numbers but my programs says they are wrong (example 2123456802). Now my question where is my mistake and/or understood I the function of the last number wrong?

Comment: What is `In.read()`? Where is that defined? Why are you using `char` rather than `int`?

Comment: For `isbn = '0'`, is that going to pass `'1' <= isbn && isbn <= '9'`? That is why that example failed, probably

Comment: In read() is like java.scanner ( In is a ectra class just for this project to get make input) and to use char is mandatory for this example (I don't know why)

Comment: next time you look something up on the Internet, actually read the article.  You are calculating the check digit incorrectly.  Here is a wikipedia page, read it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number

Comment: did tried to implement this method

Comment: You don't need to `% 11` in the loop. Just on the final sum.

Answer (score 1):

> the sum of all the ten digits, each multiplied by its (integer) weight, descending from 10 to 1, is a multiple of 11.

So you just need to sum that digit value time the weight :

```
int check = 0;
for(int weight = 10; weight > 0; weigth--){
    char c = In.read(); //get the next character
    int i;
    if( c == 'x' || c == 'X' ){ 
        i = 10;
    } else {     
        if(! Character.isDigit(c)) //Because, just in case...
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a numeric value");

        i = Character.getNumericValue( c );
    }
    check += i * weight;
}
```

Just need to check if it is a multiple of 11

```
if ( check % 11 == 0 )
    System.out.println( "VALID" );
else
    System.out.println( "INVALID" );
```

Comment: @JanM huge edit to be more on what you wrote first... because it was a bit more complicated at first

Comment: ok thanks. The only problem is now if you have a number with an x (=10) and the isbn number is ok you get the illegalArgument

Comment: @JanM Can you provide an example

Comment: yes this isbn 123456789X should be correct but when you type it in you get an IllegalArgumentException error

Comment: `X` is just a `10`, you need to add that specific condition for it.

Comment: @JanM The logic is the same, X just equals 10 (because you can't have a character `10`, it would be seen as `1` and `0`. Sum the exact same way the value. See the edit (not tested)